# imap() not working as I expected, what am I missing?

Tags: r, purrr

So here, i get errors with imap, when using the index (".y") to go through a list. below I have made it work with map2, but this is confusing, because the way I made the map2() function is exacly the same way I would've thought that imap would do it. But it clearly isn't, otherwise it wouldn't error out.

I would love to understand the purrr logic as good  as possible, could anyone tell me what's going on?

```
library(purrr)

l1 <- list(a='a', b='b')



# single brackets -  'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'
imap(l1, ~{
  y1 <- names(l1)[.y]
  if(y1 == 'a') out1 <- TRUE
  if(y1 == 'b') out1 <- FALSE
  out
})
# double brackets -  subscript out of bounds
imap(l1, ~{
  y1 <- names(l1)[[.y]]
  if(y1 == 'a') out1 <- TRUE
  if(y1 == 'b') out1 <- FALSE
  out
})


# emulating what I think imap() does 
map2(l1, seq_along(l1), ~{
  y1 <- names(l1)[.y]
  if(y1 == 'a') out1 <- TRUE
  if(y1 == 'b') out1 <- FALSE
  out1
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names are present in the list, `.y` is the name of the list and not it's index. So,

```
names(l1)['a'] #returns
#[1] NA
```

which explains `'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'`.

and

```
names(l1)[['a']]
```

returns

> Error in names(l1)[["a"]] : subscript out of bounds

What you need is -

```
purrr::imap(l1, ~{
  if(.y == 'a') out1 <- TRUE
  if(.y == 'b') out1 <- FALSE
  out1
})

#$a
#[1] TRUE

#$b
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you simply need

```
imap(l1, ~ if(.y == 'a')  TRUE else FALSE)

$a
[1] TRUE

$b
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Well, if you really want to simplify only `imap(l1, ~ .y == 'a')` is enough for this example.

Comment: In my real usercase it's way more complicated, but thanks